# Delete duplicate rows from oracle DB with one condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, dml

I have got the script right but the execution time of completion is about 5 Mins to delete 11320860 records. Is there alternate way of writing this query so that the execution time is reduced ?

Scenario is same record combination can have E as well as A records. And the code is trying to delete both A and E records if there exists at least one E record for the same combination.

```
Delete from tableA u 
WHERE EXISTS
    (Select 1 from tableA w 
    WHERE w.a = u.a
    AND w.b = u.b
    AND w.c = u.c
    AND w.d = u.d
    AND w.flag ='E' ); - Del about 11320860 records in 4 Mins
```

Comment: why not simply do, `delete from tableA where flag = 'E';` your query will have an unnecessary overhead

Comment: You can use merge

Comment: Scenario is same record combination can have E as well as A records. And the code is trying to delete both A and E records if there exists at least one E record for the same combination.

Answer (score 0):

So you need this, I think:

```
Delete from tableA u 
WHERE u.flag in ('A', 'E')
  and EXISTS
    (Select 1 from tableA w 
      WHERE w.a = u.a
        AND w.b = u.b
        AND w.c = u.c
        AND w.d = u.d
        AND w.flag ='E')
```

This way also should work:

```
delete from tableA 
  where flag in ('A', 'E')
    and (a, b, c, d) in 
    (select a, b, c, d 
       from tableA 
      where flag = 'E')
```

Comment: I added a Scenario where same record combination can have E as well as A records. And the code is trying to delete both A and E records if there exists at least one E record for the same combination.